Script/link is not loading on community though static resource
I am create a static resource file for community Site which work when site will down. I am created html,css,js under file. When i am deactivate Site, Maintenance page is showing but javascript is not working and also " " Not loading , I have clear chache and try to diffrent brower's but issue is still occurs.
Error : Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
Code :

    
    
    
    
    
          alert("This alert box was called with the onload event");
        


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
